# Cannot resize UIScrollView's Frame

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, resize, frame

I have a UIScrollView with it's frame and contentSize with the same size. I want to change the frame height of the scrollView when the keyboard appears, but it does not work.
If I change the x or y position everything works ok, but If I try to change the Width or Height of the frame, everything stays the same, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)resizeContentView:(BOOL)resize forOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        UIView* resizeView = [self getResizingView];
        if ( !resizeView )
            return;
        CGRect rect = resizeView.frame;
        if (resize)
        {
            rect.size.height -= offset;
        }
        else
        {
            rect.size.height += offset;
        }
        resizeView.frame = rect;
    }];
}
```

I am not using Autolayout, and whether I use the animation or not, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Did you try changing contentSize along with the frame?

Comment: @dariaa But I want the content size to stay the same, so the hole screen can be scrollable :/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `content size` on `keyboaardDidAppear` notifications .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

**EDITED**

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*) notif {
NSLog(@"-(void)keyboardWillShow");

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    self.scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollview.frame.size.width/2, self.scrollview.frame.size.height/3
                                       );

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
self.scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}];

}
-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*) notif {
NSLog(@"-(void)keyboardWillHide");
    self.scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: If I just change the content size it works, but if I also try to change the frame nothing at all happens.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole class code. I guess some method might be setting the `contentSize` back to frame.

Comment: I would but it's a really large class haha, I searched and I'm not setting it anywhere else. The strange behaviour is that if change the frame below the position, or content size, modification code, nothing works, neither the position modification, or content size or frame. If I remove the frame modification code, the position or content size modification works. o.O

Comment: See my code above. It works for me without animation.

Comment: @6rod9 : I update the code & now it works with animations. Please check

Comment: I cannot get it to work :/ There's something strange going on: I printed in the console the scrollview frame after keyboard show and after keyboard hide, here's what came up:
  (void)keyboardWillShow
  SCROLL:<UIScrollView: 0x8db6e10; frame = (20 20; 160 136.667)
  (void)keyboardWillHide
  SCROLL:<UIScrollView: 0x8db6e10; frame = (0 44; 320 410);
It looks like the scroll view frame get's reseted to it's original size for some reason :/

Comment: If I just modify the x or y:
contentScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, contentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.size.height);
  The animation works, but if I modify also the width and height:
        contentScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, contentScrollView.frame.size.width/2, contentScrollView.frame.size.height/3);
Nothing happens! I must be having some bug somewhere, or something wrongly configured.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49573/discussion-between-abhishek-bedi-and-6rod9)